# Active Directory: Search for only user objects

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm using the search filter "(objectClass=user)" to find user objects, but of course it also returns computers because a computer also has user in its objectClass.  How can I create a filter to only return objects users and not objects whos type inherits from user?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person))
```

(via [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms675881%28VS.85%29.aspx))

Comment: I find this one annoying as well.  Ah, the joys of inheritance.